# ng-click is not working on submit button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-click is not working when I click on submit button

```
<div ng-app="myFirstApp" ng-controller="studentController as studentController">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="studentController.student.name"/>
        <input type="text" name="class" ng-model="studentController.student.class"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="studentController.student.submit()"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Here is my code for `"Student"` factory.

```
app.factory('Student',[ function() {

// Contructor
function Student(data){
    if(data){
        this.setData(data);
    }
};

// Functions
Student.prototype = {
    setData: function(data){
        angular.extend(this,data);
    },

    new: function(){
        var studentData ={
            name:"",
            class:""
        }
        this.setData(studentData);
    },

    submit: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }


};

return Student;
}]);
```

and here is `"studentController"` code

```
app.controller('studentController',studentController);
function studentController(Student){
    var student = new Student();
    student.new();
    console.log(student);
};
```

I don't know where I am doing it wrong, I am getting not an error in console.
I have tried running other methods in `studentFactory` but not a single method is running.

Why ng-click is not working on `studentController.student.submit()` as i am using `studentController as studentController` in `<div>` tag.

Comment: Remove ng-click from submit and add it to form tag  with ng-submit <form ng-submit="studentController.student.submit()">

Comment: @Vivz still not working :(

Comment: Your mappings are wrong. Where is prototype? And don't call your functions in your view directly from factory

Comment: then how should i call them ??

Comment: @Vivz prototype is in studentFactory .

Comment: @HassanRaza Looks like you haven't bound student to the controller. Can you try using `this.student = student;` in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use following HTML

```
    <form ng-submit="studentController.student.submit()">
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="studentController.student.name"/>
        <input type="text" name="class" ng-model="studentController.student.class"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="reviewForm" novalidate="novalidate" valid-submit="submitClick()">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="studentController.student.name"/>
    <input type="text" name="class" ng-model="studentController.student.class"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**make one function submitClick() in controller.**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call directly factory's method..not from your registered controller..that will not work ever and violating angular js concept ..so define that functions in to controller and then try to call it and please provide a plunker or jsfiddle if you can ..that will make sense to us

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.controller('studentController',[studentController]);
function studentController(Student){
    var student = new Student();
    student.new();
    console.log(student);
};
```